# Как из iframe запретить доступ к родительскому окну?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Мне нужно, чтоб люди вставляли код в свой пост. У меня код людей пишется в iframe, чтоб они хулюганили. Т.е. не src = "url", а srcdoc ="код". Нужно чтоб вот такие вещи не работали

```
window.parent.document.write("<h1>Текст</h1>")
```

Т.е. у меня вот такая конструкция`<iframe srcdoc="' + переменная + '">`.

Может быть из переменной вырезать "parent"? Без какого слова нельзя будет пробраться к родителю? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант вы можете воспользоваться данным регулярным выражением для удаления скриптов:

```
var pattern = /<script(\s+(\w+\s*=\s*("|').*?\3)\s*)*\s*(\/>|>.*?<\/script\s*>)/;
var match = HTMLString.match(pattern); // получим массив совпадений с регулярным выражением
```

Далее можно воспользоваться функцией str.replace();

Также для iframe существует атрибут sandbox, который позволяет блокировать формы и скрипты.